# Is there any way of setting a value to a subclass property and it appears in a different base class property?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, properties

Is there any way of setting a value X to a subclass property (TextAnswers[]) and it appears on the base class property (Answers[])?
I had a similar problem with another two classes but as the property that I wanted was of the same type in both base class and subclass it was easy. I just let the property on the base class.

In this case, the properties are of different types (IAnswerOption and AnswerOptionImage).

In my point of view, the perfect solution is to set a property on the subclass and try to pass the value to the base class but I am getting struggled with this. I left the code below and I am available to explain it better if you do not understand what I intend.

**This is my base class:**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Question : IQuestion<IAnswerOption>
{
    public virtual IAnswerOption[] Answers { get; set; }
}
```

**This is my subclass:**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AudioQuestion : Question
{
    [field: SerializeField] private AnswerOptionImage[] answerOptions;

    public IAnswerOption[] AnswerOptions
    {
        get { return (IAnswerOption[]) answerOptions;}
        set { answerOptions = (AnswerOptionImage[]) Answers;  }
    }

    public string audioName;
}
```

The problem shows up here. I have a class that receives a Question. I created a property of Question type to be able to receive any subclass of Question. I made the debug and the problem occurs when I reach the foreach.

```
protected Question CurrentQuestion { get; set; }

public void Method() 
{
    foreach (var answer in CurrentQuestion.Answers)
    {
           
    }
}
```

**As you can see AnswerOptions is filled:**
[image]

**However CurrentQuestion.Answers is null**
[image]

*If someone can help me I would be very grateful. Thanks.*

Comment: the questions is not clear, what do you want to do? you have a class that receives a parameter of a "generic class" to allow subclasses of it to be passed, and then I didn't follow you

Comment: I have the Question class as a base class. In addition to this, I have several subclasses of Question such as AudioQuestion. Both classes have Answers. However, questions can be of various types and so can Answers. As you can see above, my problem is represented in the last two images. AnswerOptions that are part of AudioQuestion are filled but Answers that come from the base class are null. What I want is for CurrentQuestion.Answers to have the same value as AnswerOptions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Question.Answers` has a public setter; this makes it impossible to safely use a more specific type in the subclass.

For example:

```
public class SomeOtherAnswerOption : IAnswerOption { }

Question audioQuestion = new AudioQuestion();
audioQuestion.Answers = new SomeOtherAnswerOption[] { }; // You probably don't want to allow this
```

If you remove the public setter from the base class you could do something like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Question : IQuestion<IAnswerOption>
{
    public virtual IAnswerOption[] Answers { get; protected set; } // Setter protected
}

[System.Serializable]
public class AudioQuestion : Question
{
    // Hide the base property but use it in the implementation
    public new AnswerOptionImage[] Answers
    {
        get => base.Answers as AnswerOptionImage[];
        set { base.Answers = value; }
    }
}
```

The `new` keyword hides the base class property, but whether the object is being treated as a `Question` or `AudioQuestion`, the array can be retrieved:

```
AudioQuestion audioQuestion = new AudioQuestion();
audioQuestion.Answers = new AnswerOptionImage[] { };

Question question = audioQuestion;
audioQuestion.Answers == question.Answers; // true;

question.Answers = new SomeOtherAnswerOption[] { }; // Compilation error
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
    AudioQuestion audioQuestion = (AudioQuestion)unansweredQuestions[randomQuestionIndex];
    CurrentQuestion = audioQuestion;
    CurrentQuestion.Answers = audioQuestion.AnswerOptions;
```

First I stored my question in audioQuestion, then I assigned the audioquestion to the CurrentQuestion and finally, I copied my AnswerOptions[] to Answers[].

This way, when I inspect CurrentQuestion Answers[] property has the same value as AnswerOptions[].

Comment: This solution violates the open-closed principle. Each time you create a new sub-class of `Question` you need to remember to update this code as well. If you do similar things elsewhere, you have a serious maintenance problem.